# XML serialization and inheritance

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

```
class A : IXmlSerializable
{     ...
}

class B : A
{
   public string X;
}
```

When i serialize object of type B, only A is serialized. How can I include X with minimum effort?

Comment: Do you really need to implement IXmlSerializable ? Unless you're serializing to a very specific and unusual schema, XmlSerializer can handle most situations by itself

Comment: Yes, I really need to implement IXmlSerializable.

Comment: why? you can achieve almost everything by applying attributes

Comment: @Andrey because of A:Dictionary<...>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact you're implementing IXmlSerializable makes it a bit harder...

What you could do is make `WriteXml` and `ReadXml` virtual, and override them in your derived class:

```
public class A : IXmlSerializable
{
    public virtual void WriteXml (XmlWriter writer)
    {
        // Serialize A members
    }

    public virtual void ReadXml (XmlReader reader)
    {
        // Deserialize A members
    }

    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return(null);
    }


}


public class B : A
{
    public override void WriteXml (XmlWriter writer)
    {
        base.WriteXml(writer);

        // Serialize B members
    }

    public virtual void ReadXml (XmlReader reader)
    {
        base.ReadXml(reader);

        // Deserialize B members
    }
}
```